# Is there a way to have wall messages show to desktop users?

Tags: command-line, ssh, notification

Let's say I'm away from home, ssh-ing on my home computer. For any reason, I need it rebooted.

```
# shutdown -r +10
```

This sends a warning message every minute via [`wall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/wall.1.html), which is completely invisible for normal desktop use by, say, my parents.

Is there any way `wall` messages can reach the desktop via, say, notification.

Comment: Thanks to information in the answers to this post, I could [hack together](https://gist.github.com/672546) a Python program that does just what I needed. It depends on the `libnotify-bin` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The internals of `wall` and are so blocked off and ancient that there's really no way to pull the message from it once it's in there.

The only real idea put forward for this ([the problem has been discussed before](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=433960), many times) is to alter the `shutdown` and `reboot` scripts so they either make something available via dbus or (as we're only dealing with one computer and one fix) you could just have it send a notify-send message.

They *are* just scripts so you could just hack into them. But I think this is probably a cause worth pushing for. Submit a bug against Ubuntu and add your patches (just make sure they can work without needing to send the notification if there's no X environment). It's this sort of usability that we need.

I've never heard of `gxmessage` before, but I would use `notify-send`.

A full solution would need to cater for the possibility of multiple displays (eg multi-head, remote users, etc) but thankfully I wrote some code for that bit yesterday:

```
for display in `ps aux | grep -oE "/usr/bin/X\s[^ ]+" | cut -d " " -f 2`; do
    DISPLAY=$display notify-send -u critical 'Shutdown notice' 'Save all your work. THE SYSTEM IS GOING DOWN!!' -i /usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-computer.png
done
```

(I'm using export instead of a `-display` or `--display` flag because I don't know that `notify-send` takes either)

Comment: gxmessage is a ancient app. come to think of it dbus and notify-send is a much better option. Maybe i can work up something with zenity.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what's best. `zenity` warnings can be annoying if you're scrambling to get things saved before you're logged out... But `notify-send` notifications might just be ignored.

Comment: It's true that notify-send notification can be ignored but if displayed once a few ( e.g. 10 minutes ) they might do the job!

Comment: @Oli I've found you also need the XAUTHORITY environment variable correctly set for this to work, however.

Comment: `DISPLAY=$display notify-send...` will only export that value of DISPLAY for that command; not that it matters here, but it's useful elsewhere and, IMHO, a bit cleaner.

Comment: @Roger Good suggestion. It would be a bit cleaner. I guess there are some cases where DISPLAY might leak out if you export it.

Comment: @badp I can't say as I've had any problems running things from root on other users' accounts before... I might just have a lax setup though. It's a sticking point, I guess the workaround answer is having an intermediary file store the message and cronning up something to read that file (for each user/X session). Just remember to have something delete the file on boot.

Answer (score 3):

You could send a message manually using zenity

```
zenity --warning --text "badp's about to restart the computer" --display=:0
```

Of course, you could include this in a script.

Comment: I can't open the display, even as superuser (I must sudo as the right user) :(

Comment: Should be able to - sure you've got the colon in there (`=:0` not `=0`)

Comment: couldn't, you also need the XAUTHORITY environment variable correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no X client for the wall command to display these message in a graphical environment. You can use **gxmessage** app for displaying popups but then you will have to write the script yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a script that crateas a ptty and listens for written messages (from write or wall) and then forwards that on to a GUI output.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, with KDE Plasma 5.27.10 on Wayland, `wall` *does* work. I can ssh in, `wall` a message, and it'll show a notification on *all* plasma instances. (If I switch users, and then send the message, I'll see it on the current user, then if I switch back, I'll see it there, appropriately timestamped) It also indicates which user sent the message.

GNOME Shell 45.3 on Wayland *does not* support `wall` messages.

I'd recommend running the `w` or `who` commands to determine if they are on GNOME or another DE that doesn't support `wall` properly.